# How to move view with anchor out of a Coordinator Layout?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-coordinatorlayout

Suppose I have layout similar to that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottomIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:src="@drawable/some_image"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"/>

    <some.widget.SomeView
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Everything is okey, `bottomIcon` is placed above the `bottomView`. When I try to translate `bottomView` little bit up, all is still okey, `bottomIcon` is translated, too.

However when I try to translate `bottomView` down off the screen:

```
public void slideOut(View view) {
    view.animate()
        .translationY(500) //example constant
        .start();
}

//then somewhere call
slideOut(bottomView)
```

The `bottomView` moved off the screen followed by `bottomIcon`, until it reaches bottom bound of CoordinatorLayout. Then `bottomIcon` does not move down.

How can I achieve anchored view (`bottomIcon`) follow its anchor ('bottomView') even when anchor goes off screen? (the more simple and elegant the solution, the better)